# What is this JS pattern and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs, es6-modules

`onSelect(option, (0, _getOptionText2.default)(option))`

I saw this in one of the node modules I use and I'm pretty confused by the second argument which is wrapped by parentheses. How does that work? There is no function which it is invoking.